# Jenkins not asking for credentials

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I am trying to install jenkins on EKS using helm
Below is the command

helm install test jenkins/jenkins --namespace jenkins --version 3.2.0 -f helm-jenkins-config.yaml

repo url is:- https://charts.jenkins.io

Below is the error log

No hudson.security.AuthorizationStrategy implementation found for projectMatrix

Below is my config file

```
# Default values for jenkins.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare name/value pairs to be passed into your templates.
# name: value

## Overrides for generated resource names
# See templates/_helpers.tpl
# nameOverride:
# fullnameOverride:
# namespaceOverride:

# For FQDN resolving of the controller service. Change this value to match your existing configuration.
# ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/dns/blob/controller/docs/specification.md
clusterZone: "cluster.local"

controller:
  httpsKeyStore:
    jenkinsHttpsJksSecretName: ''
    enable: false
    httpPort: 8081
    path: "/var/jenkins_keystore"
    fileName: "keystore.jks"
    password: "password"
    # Convert keystore.jks files content to base64 ( cat keystore.jks | base64 ) and put the output here
    jenkinsKeyStoreBase64Encoded: |
        /u3+7QAAAAIAAAABAAAAAQANamVua2luc2NpLmNvbQAAAW2r/b1ZAAAFATCCBP0wDgYKKwYBBAEq
        AhEBAQUABIIE6QbCqasvoHS0pSwYqSvdydMCB9t+VNfwhFIiiuAelJfO5sSe2SebJbtwHgLcRz1Z
        gMtWgOSFdl3bWSzA7vrW2LED52h+jXLYSWvZzuDuh8hYO85m10ikF6QR+dTi4jra0whIFDvq3pxe
  # Used for label app.kubernetes.io/component
  componentName: "jenkins-controller"
  image: "jenkins/jenkins"
  tag: "lts"
  imagePullPolicy: "Always"
  imagePullSecretName:
  # Optionally configure lifetime for controller-container
  lifecycle:
  #  postStart:
  #    exec:
  #      command:
  #      - "uname"
  #      - "-a"
  disableRememberMe: false
  numExecutors: 0
  # configures the executor mode of the Jenkins node. Possible values are: NORMAL or EXCLUSIVE
  executorMode: "NORMAL"
  # This is ignored if enableRawHtmlMarkupFormatter is true
  markupFormatter: plainText
  customJenkinsLabels: []
  # configAutoReload requires UseSecurity is set to true:
  adminSecurity: true

  # enables configuration done directly via XML files
  enableXmlConfig: false

  hostNetworking: false
  # When enabling LDAP or another non-Jenkins identity source, the built-in admin account will no longer exist.
  # If you disable the non-Jenkins identity store and instead use the Jenkins internal one,
  # you should revert controller.adminUser to your preferred admin user:
  adminUser: "admin"
  # adminPassword: <defaults to random>
  admin:
    existingSecret: ""
    userKey: jenkins-admin-user
    passwordKey: jenkins-admin-password

  jenkinsHome: "/var/jenkins_home"

  jenkinsRef: "/usr/share/jenkins/ref"
  rollingUpdate: {}
  # Ignored if Persistence is enabled
  # maxSurge: 1
  # maxUnavailable: 25%
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "50m"
      memory: "256Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "1000m"
      memory: "1024Mi"
  usePodSecurityContext: true
  # Set runAsUser to 1000 to let Jenkins run as non-root user 'jenkins' which exists in 'jenkins/jenkins' docker image.
  # When setting runAsUser to a different value than 0 also set fsGroup to the same value:
  runAsUser: 1000
  fsGroup: 1000
  servicePort: 8080
  targetPort: 8080
  # For minikube, set this to NodePort, elsewhere use LoadBalancer
  # Use ClusterIP if your setup includes ingress controller
  serviceType: NodePort
  # Jenkins controller service annotations
  serviceAnnotations: {}
  # Jenkins controller custom labels
  deploymentLabels: {}
  #   foo: bar
  #   bar: foo
  # Jenkins controller service labels
  serviceLabels: {}
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: https
  # Put labels on Jenkins controller pod
  podLabels: {}
  # Used to create Ingress record (should used with ServiceType: ClusterIP)
  # nodePort: <to set explicitly, choose port between 30000-32767
  # Enable Kubernetes Liveness and Readiness Probes
  # ~ 2 minutes to allow Jenkins to restart when upgrading plugins. Set ReadinessTimeout to be shorter than LivenessTimeout.
  healthProbes: true
  healthProbesLivenessTimeout: 5
  healthProbesReadinessTimeout: 5
  healthProbeLivenessPeriodSeconds: 10
  healthProbeReadinessPeriodSeconds: 10
  healthProbeLivenessFailureThreshold: 5
  healthProbeReadinessFailureThreshold: 3
  healthProbeLivenessInitialDelay: 190
  healthProbeReadinessInitialDelay: 160
  agentListenerPort: 50000
  agentHostPort:
  disabledAgentProtocols:
    - JNLP-connect
    - JNLP2-connect
  csrf:
    defaultCrumbIssuer:
      enabled: true
      proxyCompatability: true
  cli: false
  # Kubernetes service type for the JNLP agent service
  # agentListenerServiceType is the Kubernetes Service type for the JNLP agent service,
  # either 'LoadBalancer', 'NodePort', or 'ClusterIP'
  # Note if you set this to 'LoadBalancer', you *must* define annotations to secure it. By default
  # this will be an external load balancer and allowing inbound 0.0.0.0/0, a HUGE
  # security risk:  https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/issues/1341
  agentListenerServiceType: "ClusterIP"
  # Optionally assign an IP to the LoadBalancer agentListenerService LoadBalancer
  # GKE users: only regional static IPs will work for Service Load balancer.
  # agentListenerLoadBalancerIP: 1.2.3.4
  agentListenerServiceAnnotations: {}
  agentDefaultsProviderTemplate: ""
  agentConnectTimeout: 5
  agentReadTimeout: 15
  agentKubernetesNamespace:
  agentJenkinsUrl:
  agentJenkinsTunnel:


  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 0.0.0.0/0

  extraPorts: []
  # - name: BuildInfoProxy
  #   port: 9000

  # List of plugins to be install during Jenkins controller start
  installPlugins:
    - kubernetes:1.30.1
    - workflow-job:2.41
    - workflow-aggregator:2.6
    - credentials-binding:1.26
    - git:4.5.2
    - configuration-as-code:1.51
    - kubernetes-cli:1.8.3

  additionalPlugins: []


  controller.overwritePluginsFromImage: true


  enableRawHtmlMarkupFormatter: false
  # Used to approve a list of groovy functions in pipelines used the script-security plugin. Can be viewed under /scriptApproval
  scriptApproval: []

  initScripts: []

  jobs: {}

  JCasC:
    enabled: true
    defaultConfig: true
    configScripts: {}

    securityRealm: |-
      local:
        allowsSignup: false
        #users:
        #- id: "${chart-admin-username}"
        #  name: "Jenkins Admin"
        #  password: "${chart-admin-password}"
          #authorizationStrategy: |-
          #loggedInUsersCanDoAnything:
          #allowAnonymousRead: false
  
    authorizationStrategy: |-
     projectMatrix:
       permissions: 
         - "Overall/Administer:admin"
    # welcome-message: |
    #   jenkins:
    #     systemMessage: Welcome to our CI\CD server.  This Jenkins is configured and managed 'as code'.
  # Optionally specify additional init-containers
  customInitContainers: []
  # - name: custom-init
  #   image: "alpine:3.7"
  #   imagePullPolicy: Always
  #   command: [ "uname", "-a" ]

  sidecars:
    configAutoReload:
      
      enabled: true
      image: kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar:0.1.144
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      resources: {}
        
    
      sshTcpPort: 1044
      
      folder: "/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs"
    

    
    other: []

  nodeSelector:
    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup: test
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds:

  tolerations: []
  
  # priorityClass: system-cluster-critical
  podAnnotations: {}

  deploymentAnnotations: {}

  customConfigMap: false

  overwriteConfig: false


  overwriteJobs: false

  ingress:
    enabled: false
    
    paths: []

    apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
    labels: {}
    annotations: {}

    hostName:
    tls:
  

  # If you're running on GKE and need to configure a backendconfig
  # to finish ingress setup, use the following values.
  # Docs: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/backendconfig
  backendconfig:
    enabled: false
    apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
    name:
    labels: {}
    annotations: {}
    spec: {}

  # Openshift route
  route:
    enabled: false
    labels: {}
    annotations: {}
    # path: "/jenkins"

  additionalConfig: {}

  # controller.hostAliases allows for adding entries to Pod /etc/hosts:
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/
  hostAliases: []
  # - ip: 192.168.50.50
  #   hostnames:
  #     - something.local
  # - ip: 10.0.50.50
  #   hostnames:
  #     - other.local

  # Expose Prometheus metrics
  prometheus:
    # If enabled, add the prometheus plugin to the list of plugins to install
    # https://plugins.jenkins.io/prometheus
    enabled: false
    # Additional labels to add to the ServiceMonitor object
    serviceMonitorAdditionalLabels: {}
    # Set a custom namespace where to deploy ServiceMonitor resource
    # serviceMonitorNamespace: monitoring
    scrapeInterval: 60s
    # This is the default endpoint used by the prometheus plugin
    scrapeEndpoint: /prometheus
    # Additional labels to add to the PrometheusRule object
    alertingRulesAdditionalLabels: {}
    # An array of prometheus alerting rules
    # See here: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/
    # The `groups` root object is added by default, simply add the rule entries
    alertingrules: []

  # Can be used to disable rendering controller test resources when using helm template
  testEnabled: true

agent:
  enabled: true
  image: "xxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/swf"
  tag: "xxxxx"
  workingDir: "/home/jenkins"
  customJenkinsLabels: []
  # name of the secret to be used for image pulling
  imagePullSecretName:
  componentName: "jenkins-agent"
  privileged: false
  runAsUser:
  runAsGroup:
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "200m"
      memory: "256Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "1000m"
      memory: "1046Mi"
  # You may want to change this to true while testing a new image
  alwaysPullImage: false

  podRetention: "Never"
  
  volumes: []

  envVars: []

  #nodeSelector: {}
  nodeSelector:
    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup: test
  # Key Value selectors. Ex:
  # jenkins-agent: v1

  # Executed command when side container gets started
  command:
  args: "${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}"
  # Side container name
  sideContainerName: "jnlp"
  # Doesn't allocate pseudo TTY by default
  TTYEnabled: false
  # Max number of spawned agent
  containerCap: 10
  # Pod name
  podName: "default"
  # Allows the Pod to remain active for reuse until the configured number of
  # minutes has passed since the last step was executed on it.
  idleMinutes: 0
  # Raw yaml template for the Pod. For example this allows usage of toleration for agent pods.
  # https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#using-yaml-to-define-pod-templates
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
  yamlTemplate: ""
  # yamlTemplate: |-
  #   apiVersion: v1
  #   kind: Pod
  #   spec:
  #     tolerations:
  #     - key: "key"
  #       operator: "Equal"
  #       value: "value"
  # Defines how the raw yaml field gets merged with yaml definitions from inherited pod templates: merge or override
  yamlMergeStrategy: "override"
  # Timeout in seconds for an agent to be online
  agentConnectTimeout: 100

  # Below is the implementation of custom pod templates for the default configured kubernetes cloud.
  # Add a key under podTemplates for each pod template. Each key (prior to | character) is just a label, and can be any value.
  # Keys are only used to give the pod template a meaningful name.  The only restriction is they may only contain RFC 1123 \ DNS label
  # characters: lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. Each pod template can contain multiple containers.
  # For this pod templates configuration to be loaded the following values must be set:
  # controller.JCasC.enabled: true
  # controller.JCasC.defaultConfig: true
  # Best reference is https://<jenkins_url>/configuration-as-code/reference#Cloud-kubernetes. The example below creates a python pod template.
  podTemplates: {}
  #  python: |
  #    - name: python
  #      label: jenkins-python
  #      serviceAccount: jenkins
  #      containers:
  #        - name: python
  #          image: python:3
  #          command: "/bin/sh -c"
  #          args: "cat"
  #          ttyEnabled: true
  #          privileged: true
  #          resourceRequestCpu: "400m"
  #          resourceRequestMemory: "512Mi"
  #          resourceLimitCpu: "1"
  #          resourceLimitMemory: "1024Mi"

# Here you can add additional agents
# They inherit all values from `agent` so you only need to specify values which differ
additionalAgents: {}
#  maven:
#    podName: maven
#    customJenkinsLabels: maven
#    # An example of overriding the jnlp container
#    # sideContainerName: jnlp
#    image: jenkins/jnlp-agent-maven
#    tag: latest
#  python:
#    podName: python
#    customJenkinsLabels: python
#    sideContainerName: python
#    image: python
#    tag: "3"
#    command: "/bin/sh -c"
#    args: "cat"
#    TTYEnabled: true

persistence:
  enabled: true
  ## A manually managed Persistent Volume and Claim
  ## Requires persistence.enabled: true
  ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
  existingClaim:
  ## jenkins data Persistent Volume Storage Class
  ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
  ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
  ##
  storageClass:
  annotations: {}
  accessMode: "ReadWriteOnce"
  size: "8Gi"
  volumes:
  #  - name: nothing
  #    emptyDir: {}
  mounts:
  #  - mountPath: /var/nothing
  #    name: nothing
  #    readOnly: true

networkPolicy:
  # Enable creation of NetworkPolicy resources.
  enabled: false
  # For Kubernetes v1.4, v1.5 and v1.6, use 'extensions/v1beta1'
  # For Kubernetes v1.7, use 'networking.k8s.io/v1'
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  # You can allow agents to connect from both within the cluster (from within specific/all namespaces) AND/OR from a given external IP range
  internalAgents:
    allowed: true
    namespaceLabels: {}
      # project: myproject
  externalAgents: {}
  #   ipCIDR: 172.17.0.0/16
  #   except:
  #     - 172.17.1.0/24

## Install Default RBAC roles and bindings
rbac:
  create: true
  readSecrets: false

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  # The name of the service account is autogenerated by default
  name:
  annotations: {}

serviceAccountAgent:
  # Specifies whether a ServiceAccount should be created
  create: false
  # The name of the ServiceAccount to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name:
  annotations: {}

## Backup cronjob configuration
## Ref: https://github.com/maorfr/kube-tasks
backup:
  # Backup must use RBAC
  # So by enabling backup you are enabling RBAC specific for backup
  enabled: false
  # Used for label app.kubernetes.io/component
  componentName: "backup"

  schedule: "0 2 * * *"
  labels: {}
  annotations: {}
  
  image:
    repository: "maorfr/kube-tasks"
    tag: "0.2.0"

  extraArgs: []

  existingSecret: {}


  env: []

  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 1Gi
      cpu: 1
    limits:
      memory: 1Gi
      cpu: 2
  
  destination: "s3://jenkins-data/backup"
checkDeprecation: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Made below changes and it worked

```
securityRealm: |-
      local:
        allowsSignup: false
        users:
        - id: "${chart-admin-username}"
          name: "Jenkins Admin"
          password: "${chart-admin-password}"
          #authorizationStrategy: |-
          #loggedInUsersCanDoAnything:
          #allowAnonymousRead: false
  
   # authorizationStrategy: |-
    # projectMatrix:
     #  permissions: 
      #   - "Overall/Administer:admin"
```